How to express these lifetime bounds
I'm writing a "coiterator" trait in rust (and a bunch of adapters for it):
pub trait Consumer<Item> {
    type Output;

    fn eat(&mut self, item: Item) -> Option<()>;

    fn finish(self) -> Self::Output;

    fn pair_with_iterator(mut self, iterator: impl IntoIterator<Item = Item>) -> Self::Output
    where
        Self: Sized,
    {
        for item in iterator {
            if self.eat(item).is_none() {
                break;
            }
        }
        self.finish()
    }

    ...
}

Think of eat as the dual of Iterator::next and finish as the dual of IntoIterator::into_iter. Now, if I have a Consumer<T> and a Consumer<&T> then I can combine them to process the same items in parallel. For example, you might have one type that collects an iterator into a HashSet and another that just counts the number of items. I know how to write that using just iterators but consider the following general implementation:
struct Parallel<C, D> {
    by_move: C,
    by_ref: D,
}

// this is wrong, T should not need to live for 'static
impl<T: 'static, C: Consumer<T>, D: for<'a> Consumer<&'a T>> Consumer<T> for Parallel<C, D> {
    type Output = (C::Output, <D as Consumer<&'static T>>::Output);

    fn eat(&mut self, item: T) -> Option<()> {
        self.by_ref.eat(&item)?;
        self.by_move.eat(item)
    }

    fn finish(self) -> Self::Output {
        (self.by_move.finish(), self.by_ref.finish())
    }
}

But as in the comment, the lifetime bounds are not what they should be. The underlying issue is that there's no way (I think) to represent that <D as Consumer<&'a T>>::Output should not depend on the lifetime 'a. I have also considered the following fixes, but I don't think any of these work:

Make Item an associated type rather than an input type to Consumer. Then you just cannot have D that accepts &'a T for multiple 'a and I don't see how to implement eat for Parallel.
D as Consumer<&'static T> could have, instead of 'static, whatever the lifetime of T is, but I again think there's no way to express that. Similarly for a hypothetical 'zero or 'temp lifetime (the opposite of 'static) so that T: 'zero would be automatic for any T.
Replace 'static by some generic lifetime 'b, but then it would be unconstrained.

Is there a way to write a more general version of this impl that doesn't need the bound on T?

"you might have one type that collects an iterator into a HashSet" ... okay, so if the borrowed Items are collected into a HashSet, then each of those borrows must outlive the calls to eat; how then can an Item also be moved into the other call?  Surely you're going to need a clone?

@eggyal If I have an iterator of Ts then I can either count() it to get a usize or collect() it to a HashSet<T>. But I can also do something like iter.inspect(|_: &T| count += 1).collect() to get both at the same time and without any cloning. In any case, if T does live for 'static then the code in the question works (and it's not too hard to write Consumer types corresponding to collect() and count()).

The code in the question only appears to work because the D consumer can eat any lifetime of borrow but is required to output a type that is 'static.  A consumer that collects its items into a HashSet therefore cannot be provided as D since the output set would not satisfy the 'static constraint.

@eggyal of course, C would be the collect() and D would be the count(). I don't really understand your objection.

Right, but you're writing code that's intended/required to be more general: where D could in fact be a "collector".  There's nothing that stops a user providing such.  And then you will see the need for clone per my first comment.

@eggyal Of course the "collector" Consumer should not satisfy for<'a> Consumer<&'a T> unless T is Clone.

It seems to me you may need to define separate traits for Collect etc, to refine the capabilities/requirements of the generics in this impl.

I believe you just need to place a lifetime on either Consumer or Parallel so that you have a named lifetime to use in the definition of Output. Parallel probably makes more sense because it has an intrinsic (albeit hidden) lifetime, whereas if the lifetime were placed on Consumer, every implementer would need to reference it even if they didn't make use of it.
use std::{collections::HashSet, hash::Hash, marker::PhantomData};

pub trait Consumer<Item> {
    type Output;

    fn eat(&mut self, item: Item) -> Option<()>;

    fn finish(self) -> Self::Output;

    fn pair_with_iterator(mut self, iterator: impl IntoIterator<Item = Item>) -> Self::Output
    where
        Self: Sized,
    {
        for item in iterator {
            if self.eat(item).is_none() {
                break;
            }
        }
        self.finish()
    }
}

struct Parallel<'a, C, D> {
    by_move: C,
    by_ref: D,
    phantom: PhantomData<&'a ()>,
}

impl<'a, T: 'a, C: Consumer<T>, D: for<'b> Consumer<&'b T>> Consumer<T> for Parallel<'a, C, D> {
    type Output = (C::Output, <D as Consumer<&'a T>>::Output);

    fn eat(&mut self, item: T) -> Option<()> {
        self.by_ref.eat(&item)?;
        self.by_move.eat(item)
    }

    fn finish(self) -> Self::Output {
        (self.by_move.finish(), self.by_ref.finish())
    }
}

impl<T: Hash + Eq> Consumer<T> for HashSet<T> {
    type Output = Self;

    fn eat(&mut self, item: T) -> Option<()> {
        self.insert(item);
        Some(())
    }

    fn finish(self) -> Self::Output {
        self
    }
}

impl<T> Consumer<T> for usize {
    type Output = Self;

    fn eat(&mut self, _item: T) -> Option<()> {
        *self += 1;
        Some(())
    }

    fn finish(self) -> Self::Output {
        self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![0, 1, 2, 2, 0];
    let par = Parallel {
        by_move: HashSet::new(),
        by_ref: 0_usize,
        phantom: PhantomData,
    };
    let (set, count) = par.pair_with_iterator(v.iter());
    println!("saw {count:?} items; result is {set:?}");
}

saw 5 items; result is {1, 2, 0}


@ronno You're right, I've moved the lifetime from Consumer to Parallel, which is probably the correct location for it.

Yup, that makes a lot of sense
